# Adding a $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have been working on this tutorial: [Thinkster MEAN tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/)

I am trying to add another `$stateProvider` to the project. It will be used to create comments to existing comments but I don't how to use its `:id`. 
Below is the code I tried:

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: '/home.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  resolve: {
      postPromise: ['posts', function (posts) {
          return posts.getAll();
      }]
  }
})
.state('posts', {
    url: '/posts/:id',
    templateUrl: '/posts.html',
    controller: 'PostsCtrl',
    resolve: {
        post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function ($stateParams, posts) {
            return posts.get($stateParams.id);
        }]
    }
})
.state('comments', {
    url: '/comments/:id',
    templateUrl: '/comments.html',
    controller: 'CommentsCtrl',
    resolve: {
        post: ['$stateParams', 'comments', function ($stateParams, comments) {
            return comments.get($stateParams.id);
        }]
    }
});
```

For the `comments` state, I know the code is wrong but I just put some code in it for better understanding. I got confused with what I need to with it, so I tried to change the `url: '/posts/:id/comments/:id'` but it didn't work.

Also I want to know whether below code can be used for its navigation:

```
<a href="#/comments/{{comment._id}}"> // don't know whether it's correct
    {{comment.body}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$stateProvider` code which you have written is right, You should use `ui-sref` directive to create `href` attribute

```
<a ui-sref="comments({id: comment._id})"> // will create a href
    {{comment.body}}
</a>
```

Comment: What about the comments `$stateProvider`, is it correct?

Comment: @RaghavMac yes its accurate I think..It should work now

Comment: @RaghavMac does url getting change in URL bar of browser..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83685/discussion-between-raghav-mac-and-pankaj-parkar).